# .NET image.Save, what format is the file saved in?

Tags: .net, image

When I use, e.g. in C# the image class which implements the Save method, what format will the file be?
I assume it will be what I enter to save dialog but what if I enter some nonsense extension?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't specify format the image will be saved to the format returned by [Image.RawFormat Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rawformat.aspx). This means that it does not matter what you enter in the filename. The RawFormat property returns the format returned by native GdipGetImageRawFormat function which should correspond to the current format of the image.

Comment: Well then what is the save file dialog good for? I should specify some extension there

Comment: If you want to use the format which corresponds to the extension entered by the user you should manually pass the corresponding format to the Save method.

Comment: How could I do that when using the Save dialog? Thanks

Answer (score 6):

**EDIT: BMP is the default format.**

Seems that *PNG* is the default format. The Save() method does provide overrides to specify different formats.

```
 Image.Save("c:\\myimage.gif", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

The file extension has no bearing on the actual image format used.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ktx83wah.aspx

Comment: Also when I enter xxx.bmp to save dialog, BMP will be used? If I write xxx.abc, PNG will be used?

Comment: @Cocodrilo: No if you won't specify format it will create a BMP, otherwise it will use the format you specified. I think default is BMP, not PNG.

Comment: @Cocodrilo - this answer is incorrect. png is used as an encoder not as a format. For example if you load a bmp file and call save without specifying format new image will still be a bitmap as .Net Framework will detect the format of the original image.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I misread the MSDN Article. Thanks for pointing it out.